# Как сравнить дату с сегодняшней в MySQL запросе?

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно сравнить дату с сегодняшней или другой определенной датой (например -10 дней) в самом запросе, чтоб составить выборку. В саму ячейку дата помещается через функцию `time()`:

```
$date = date("Y-m-d",time());
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date('Y-m-d',`date`)='".$date."'"));
```

Пишет ошибку: `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вот [это](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Date_and_time_functions.html) должно помочь.

Answer (score 1):

Сильно не увлекался данными возможностями **MySQL**, но вот что надумал когда-то очень давно :

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM m_uonline WHERE (NOW() - updated) >= 300");
```

В таблицу **m_uonline** в поле **updated** данные заносились с помощью **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** и это работало, мне нужно было удалить пользователей, которые не отмечались уже 300 секунд(5 минут), **NOW()** это внутренняя функция **MySQL** формирует текущую дату и время.

Надеюсь пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

Поможет функция `TIMESTAMPDIFF (interval, timestamp1, timestamp2)`

например для твоей разницы в 10 дней :

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (DAY, NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 10 DAY) FROM table_date
```

Comment: >>например для твоей разницы в 10 дней :
>>SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF (DAY, NOW(), NOW() + INTERVAL 5 DAY) FROM table_date
Очень интересный подход к построению SQL запросов...
Этот запрос, уважаемые @alter_f4 и @Iranda, не нуждается в части FROM и всегда возвращает число 5, не имеющее никакого отношения к разнице в 10 дней.

Comment: Возвращает именно разницу в днях между двумя датами, этот пример не более чем показательный. Просто приведен пример использования функции, которая может решить данную проблему.

Comment: Очень интересный подход к построению SQL запросов... Этот запрос, уважаемые @alter_f4 и @Iranda, не нуждается в части FROM и всегда возвращает число 5, не имеющее никакого отношения к разнице в 10 дней.

Comment: Я в курсе той информации, ссылку на которую дал.
Просто не вижу смысла составлять левый запрос из уже доступной в ответе информации.

Comment: "всегда возвращает число 5, не имеющее никакого отношения к разнице в 10 дней."
Судя из этого не совсем было понятно что вы понимаете, о чем написано в вашей ссылке =)

Answer (score 0):

1) Сегодняшний день:

```
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date('".$date."')=curdate()"));
```

2)10 дней назад:

```
mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE date('".$date."')=date_add(curdate(),INTERVAL - 10 DAY)"));
```

Comment: доброго времени у меня похожая проблема - не стал создавать вопрос тут и так много подобного у меня не работает такое: $tmp = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM stactions WHERE  STR_TO_DATE (fdate, '%Y-%m=%d') <= STR_TO_DATE ('$datenow', '%Y-%m=%d') AND STR_TO_DATE (tohda, '%Y-%m=%d') <= STR_TO_DATE ('$datenow', '%Y-%m=%d')");

Comment: @dantelol, а зачем переводить на STR_TO_DATE ? есть же DATE(), DATE_FORMAT